# Is it possible to run 64-bit software on a 32-bit operating system?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, x86

I have a program that is designed for a 64-bit OS, but I only have a 32-bit OS at the moment. Is there any way to convert the program to 32-bit or install the 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: You could run it on an emulator, but it would be incredibly slow.

Comment: The simple solution would be to use the 32-bit version of the program.  If there is no 32-bit version of the program then your only choice is to use a 64-vit version of the operating system.  **ANY** Windows 7 License allows you to install either one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you need to run it under a 64-bit version of Windows. Alternately, if your hardware supports it you can install Windows 7 x64 in a VM (Virtual Machine) and then run the app on it.

See the following threads for details:

- [Can I run 64-bit VM guests on a 32-bit host?](https://serverfault.com/questions/64127/can-i-run-64-bit-vm-guests-on-a-32-bit-host)
- [Can an x86 host run x64 guests?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52442/can-an-x86-host-run-x64-guests)

Answer (score 1):

You can't run them directly on a 32-bit OS, but if the CPU is capable of 64-bit operations (most of recent CPUs are), you can use [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and install a 64-bit guest operating system.

[Can I run a 64-bit VMware image on a 32-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine)